# Why the output of the Promise is not "1 2 3" but "1 3 2"?

Tags: javascript

```
a = function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        console.log(1);
        resolve('next');
    }).then(function() {
        console.log(2);
        return;
    });
};

b = function() {
    console.log(3);
};

a().then(b());
```

I thought that after resolve "next", it will call the function that output "2" and I couldn't understand why "console.log(3)" happen first(asynchronous?).I wonder which part I misunderstand about the usage of Promise.

Comment: TIL promise resolution is always asynchronous. I thought the `then` callback would be called as soon as it's added to a promise that has already been resolved, but apparently it still goes for a spin in the event loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a().then(b());
```

Calls `a`, which sets up the promise. The `1` is logged while setting up in the constructor. `b` is called when you did `b()`, thus logging `3`. What you passed to `then` there isn't the `b` function *but the result returned by calling `b` (which is `undefined`)*. Then when you resolve the promise, it then logs the `2`.

Your code should be like to get "1 2 3".

```
a().then(b);
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably meant to write `a().then(b)`. By writing `a().then(b())`, you're *calling* `b()` before you call `then`.

Comment: you mean `a()`, not `a` :)

Comment: Wow, you guys are fast!